# Look for the same value in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Basically I have an array links and an array linksElem, I want to check if the gridId element of the array(links) is present in the linksElem array. I am expecting a boolean

```
const lks = [
  { g: 10, conon: {} },
  { g: 10, conon: {} }, { g: 10, conon: {} }, { g: 10, conon: {} },
];

const l = [
   { g: 10, conon: {} },


const res = 
l?.some((el) => el.gr === l.g);
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? A boolean, an array of found ids?

Comment: "I am expecting a boolean" for each ID? Or do you want to check if any/some id's are matching?

Comment: Change your res variable like this and check `const res = 
links?.some((el, index) => el.gridId === linksElem[index].GridId);` and then try printing the `res` value to get actual boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.. this will return true if any of gridId in links exists in gridId of linksElem

```
          var linkids = linksElem.map(d=>d.GridId)
          var res = links.some(d=> linkids.includes(d.gridId))
          console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the following code but unfortunately it is of O(n^2) but i will write a solution of O(n) afterwards

```
const existsInLinksElem = (gridId)=>{
  for (const item of LinksElem) {
    if(item.gridId===gridId) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

and you can call this function for each element in the links array

if you would like to do it fatser you'd better change the way you are storing your data from an array to an object with the keys being the gridIds in this way :

```
const links = [
  { gridId: 106590, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106596, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 107014, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} }
];

const linksElem = {
  106590:{ GridId: 106590, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  106596:{ GridId: 106596, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  106578:{ GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  107014:{ GridId: 107014, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  106578:{ GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) }
};
```

and the function would be like:

```
const existsInLinksElem = (gridId)=>{
 return !!(linksElem[gridId])
}
```

note that you will loose nothing because anywhere that you've used the array of linkElems, you can use Object.values(linkElems) instead and have the exact same array returned

Answer (score 0):

Just change `el.gridId === linksElem.GridId` to `linksElem.map(({GridId}) => GridId).includes( el.gridId )` and you're good to go. Therefore the key method here is **`Array#includes`**. Not so sure why you're using `?`

```js
const links = [
  { gridId: 106590, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106596, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 107014, configuration: {} },
  { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} }
];

const linksElem = [
  { GridId: 106590, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  { GridId: 106596, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  { GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  { GridId: 107014, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
  { GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) }
];


const res = links.some(el => linksElem.map(({GridId}) => GridId).includes( el.gridId ) );

console.log( res );
```

**A Better Approach**

To prevent having to use `Array#map` in each iteration of `Array#some` you can determine ids in advance as follows:

```js
    const links = [
      { gridId: 106590, configuration: {} },
      { gridId: 106596, configuration: {} },
      { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} },
      { gridId: 107014, configuration: {} },
      { gridId: 106578, configuration: {} }
    ];

    const linksElem = [
      { GridId: 106590, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
      { GridId: 106596, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
      { GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
      { GridId: 107014, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) },
      { GridId: 106578, IsFamily: true, Total: 0, Tables: Array(0) }
    ];
    
    const GridIds = linksElem.map(({GridId}) => GridId);

    const res = links.some(el => GridIds.includes( el.gridId ) );

    console.log( res );
```